# Store get metadata file name output to set variable activity to use in out look email activity in logic app in Azure Data Factory

Tags: email, azure-data-factory, metadata

I am trying to grab the file name that was obtained from a get metadata activity from a SFTP and store that in a variable which I will then reference in the JSON body of a web activity which will be linked to a logic app that sends an email with that file name in the body of the email.

I do not have permissions in this scenario to use any of the "get blob" or SFTP activities so my workaround needs to be within the pipeline itself to pass to the LA, however, I cannot seem to get the file name. I have tried setting the variable with using the output of my get meta data activity with childItems @activity(get_metadata_activity_name).output.childItems and with the item name but it has not worked. Lookup does not seem to be useful here as I do not want the the content of the file.

Comment: what do you by you don't have permissions in this scenario to use any of the "get blob" or SFTP activities.

Answer (score 0):

- First using get meta data activity get all the file names in your source.
  [image]
- Then take a foreach activity and Pass the childitems to for each activity.
  [image]
- Under foreach take append variable to store all the file names in an array.
  [image]
- After for each take set variable to store the all-file names into string separated by coma.
  [image]

**Now pass this string variable to your Web activity with logic app mail**